# Error in UseMethod("xgboost") : no applicable method for 'xgboost' applied to an object of class "list"

Tags: r

I use a dataset that shows companies's default with a binary variable. using xgboost I have this problem.

```
 param <- list(objective   = "binary:logistic",
+               eval_metric = "Aucklands",
+               max_depth   = 7,
+               eta         = 0.1,
+               gammma      = 1,
+               colsample_bytree = 0.5,
+               min_child_weight = 1)
> set.seed(1234)
> train.label <- as.numeric(train.label)-1
> test.label<- as.numeric(test.label)-1
> # Pass in our hyperparameteres and train the model 
> system.time(xgb <- xgboost(params  = param,
+                            data    = dtrain,
+                            label   = train.label, 
+                            nrounds = 70,
+                            print_every_n = 5,
+                            verbose = 1))
Error in UseMethod("xgboost") : 
  no applicable method for 'xgboost' applied to an object of class "list"
Timing stopped at: 0.001 0 0.001
```

I'm pretty sure the code worked first.
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of passing `param` list into `params`. Can you try passing the parameters directly into the xgboost call? For example: xgboost(objective = ...)

Comment: Isn't function `xgb.train` the one you should be calling? It has `params = list()` in its definition, `xgboost`'s first argument is not a list.

Comment: i have the same problem but instead of 'list' I have the error with 'character'...

Comment: I use my old pc with older packages and the code works. updating packages in both the computers I have the problem explained...

Comment: weird, I don't think it's the param. Can you try this, train.label <- as.numeric(iris$Species=="setosa") ; dtrain = as.matrix(iris[,1:4]) ; xgb <- xgboost(params  = param,...,data    = dtrain,label   = train.label)

Comment: I don't have the "Aucklands" metrics, so I cannot try it out... But maybe you can also omit that for a start and see whether it's an issue with your installation

Comment: '''system.time(xgb <- xgboost(params  = param,
+                            data    = dtrain,
+                            label   = train.label, 
+                            nrounds = 70,
+                            print_every_n = 5,
+                            verbose = 1))
[1] train-auc:0.855617 
[6] train-auc:0.945504 
[11] train-auc:0.971447 
[16] train-auc:0.985551 
[21] train-auc:0.995134 
[26] train-auc:0.998620 
[31] train-.......

Comment: yes, it worked, so the problem is with your input. do you mind try dput(head(dtrain,5)) and pasting the output, in your post? and dput(head(train.label,5)) as well, for that matter

Comment: '(head(dtrain,5))
5 x 25 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 25 column names ‘ratio001’, ‘ratio002’, ‘ratio003’ ... ]]
                                                                                                                        
1 -1.64 -0.03 0.39 0.33 0.33 -9.24 -185.17 -1.17 -0.75 2.23 2.03 -0.01 -160.73 -0.46 -0.50 . 1 1 1 1   . 139 117   323 3
2 -2.92 -2.38 0.66 0.26 0.13  0.67   -2.38 -0.01 -0.02 0.05 0.02 -0.42    4.16  0.27  0.68 . 1 1 1 1 410 913  22   255 2

Comment: (head(train.label,5))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Hey @AlessandroSala, it's something with your input and I have no clue what you used as dtrain. How did you create dtrain? Can you include that in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Try using xgboost::xgboost in the xgb variable. I had the same problem and it worked for me.